# Click the notification, service create a new activity, and activity create a new service

Tags: android, service

Click the notification, service create a new activity, and activity create a new service?

## Let me first describe my use case:

My App MainActivity "OnCreate" create a service that is "sticky".

In my service, I post multiple notifications when there are some notices. The notice will be there unless user enters the app and reads the notice. There is a checking of new notice in onStartCommand.

Pressing the notification will send a intent to open the MainActivity.

## My problem is:

There is Service, MainActivity and a notice.

After some time, MainActivity is killed by system.

Click the notification recreate the mainActivity. mainActivity start a "new?" service. The "new?" service create a new notification. So I am seeing multiple instants of same notice message. This is wrong. What is the correct way to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: 
Before showing the notification, check whether or not the notification already exists there.

```
if(!notificationExists()){

    showNotification;

}
```

Comment: For full implementation of this pseudo-code, please show the code where you have built and showed the notification.